# Javadoc with Ant results in strange source code errors

Tags: ant, javadoc

I try to generate Javadoc with Ant, but no files are generated. Source code errors like the text below is shown. These should not be shown, since there is nothing wrong with the source code. It can be compiled with both Eclipse and Ant without problems. How can I get Javadoc to work with Ant?

```
  [javadoc] Loading source file C:\Users\eyvind\workspaceLuna\Group_1_Memory\Memory Group\src\memory\FileManager.java...
  [javadoc] C:\Users\eyvind\workspaceLuna\Group_1_Memory\Memory Group\src\memory\FileManager.java:65: '{' expected
  [javadoc]         try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path))){
  [javadoc]            ^
  [javadoc] C:\Users\eyvind\workspaceLuna\Group_1_Memory\Memory Group\src\memory\FileManager.java:65: ')' expected
  [javadoc]         try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path))){
  [javadoc]                            ^
  [javadoc] C:\Users\eyvind\workspaceLuna\Group_1_Memory\Memory Group\src\memory\FileManager.java:65: ';' expected
  [javadoc]         try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path))){
  [javadoc]                                                                                      ^
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the Javadoc that goes with Java 7? The error message seems to say that Javadoc does not recognize a try-with-resource statement which appeared since Java 7

Comment: I updated the Javadoc and I am now using . It is still the same error: